# How to use i in data.tables to select rows of all columns based on a conditional

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table, conditional-statements

I have a dataset with 400+ columns and am trying to find out which rows have all NAs for all columns. It's not feasible to write out the names of the all the columns in a data.table framework, i.e.

```
data[is.na(colA) & is.na(colB) ... ]
```

Is there a way do this easily across all columns? Here's a toy dataset that has one row that's all NAs and one that's all 1. What would be the best way to return the row that has all the NAs? Is there a similar way to return the rows with all 1 s? Thanks!

```
> toy <- data.table(cbind(A1 = c(1,5,6,NA,1),
+                         B1 = c(1,NA,4,NA,0),
+                         C1 = c(1,1,6,NA,10),
+                         D1 = c(1,NA,4,NA,5),
+                         E1 = c(1,2,11,NA,8)))
> toy
   A1 B1 C1 D1 E1
1:  1  1  1  1  1
2:  5 NA  1 NA  2
3:  6  4  6  4 11
4: NA NA NA NA NA
5:  1  0 10  5  8
> # the goal
> toy[1]
   A1 B1 C1 D1 E1
1:  1  1  1  1  1
> toy[4]
   A1 B1 C1 D1 E1
1: NA NA NA NA NA
```

Comment: You can try `toy[toy[, rowSums(is.na(.SD)) == length(.SD)]]` Not sure how efficient that is though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Literal implementation:

```r
toy[rowSums(sapply(toy, is.na)) == ncol(toy), ]
#    A1 B1 C1 D1 E1
# 1: NA NA NA NA NA

toy[rowSums(toy == 1) == ncol(toy),]
#    A1 B1 C1 D1 E1
# 1:  1  1  1  1  1
```

Slight improvement, removing a call to `ncol(toy)`, though I suspect that believing this will give a speed improvement is wishful-thinking:

```r
toy[rowSums(sapply(toy, Negate(is.na))) == 0, ]
toy[rowSums(toy != 1) == 0,]
```

Comment: I frequently forget that some of those functions work on the whole, thanks chinsoon12

Answer (score 2):

Here is an option with `Reduce`

```
library(data.table)
toy[toy[, Reduce(`&`, lapply(.SD, is.na))]]
#   A1 B1 C1 D1 E1
#1: NA NA NA NA NA

toy[toy[, Reduce(`&`, lapply(.SD, `==`, 1))]]
#    A1 B1 C1 D1 E1
# 1:  1  1  1  1  1
```